# Dúvida de acessar o this em prototype

Tags: javascript, protótipo

Estou tentando acessar algumas variáveis dentro do this (Orientação a Objeto) usando Object.prototype, porem em um certo ponto estou em duvida se estou fazendo da forma correta:

**Esta e a função principal:**

```
function smartPlayer(){
    this.trackCurrentInfo;
    this.tracksList;
    this.trackCurrentList;
    this.teste = "Esta tudo ok";

    this.initPlayer();
};
```

Nesta parte ainda esta tudo ok:

```
smartPlayer.prototype.initPlayer = function(){
    var self = this;

    /* Event button play */
    playMusic.addEventListener("click", function(){
        if (self.trackCurrentInfo === undefined) {
            self.trackList = getDailyrMusic();
            self.trackCurrentList = 0;
        }

        var track = self.trackList[self.trackCurrentList];
        smartPlayer.prototype._callTrack(self, track);
    });
}
```

Repare que apenas consigo acessar o this, usando o self = this; Isto é o correto, mas quando chamo a função **smartPlayer.prototype._callTrack(self, track);**, tenho que passar o self para ainda conseguir acessar a o this da função principal que e: smartPlayer();.

Dentro desta função tenho o seguinte:

```
smartPlayer.prototype._callTrack = function(self, array){
    /* set current Track infos */
    this.trackCurrentInfo = {
        "trackAlbumId": array.trackId,
        "trackMusic": array.trackName,
        "trackArtist": array.trackArtist,
        "trackAlbum": array.trackAlbum,
        "trackAlbumCover": array.trackCover,
        "trackCurrentTime": 0,
        "trackFullTime": array.trackDuration
    };

    // update elements
    // console.log(this.trackCurrentInfo)
    trackMusic.innerHTML = self.trackCurrentInfo.trackMusic;
    trackArtist.innerHTML = self.trackCurrentInfo.trackArtist;
    trackAlbum.innetHTML = self.trackCurrentInfo.trackAlbum;

}
```

Esta seria a forma correta de eu conseguir acessar o this dentro de smartPlayer()? Pois desta forma eu terei de ser sempre obrigado a passar o self em todas as funções que estão armazenando algum valor dentro do this.

Encontrei este problema sempre que passo algo dentre as funções(123).

Comment: calltrack e uma funcao dentro de smartplayer?

Comment: a função smartplayer()

Comment: voce nao pode usar o this direto? Ou criar a var self dentro da funcao smartplayer ao inves de dentro do prototipo?

Comment: Não, pois quando uso o this dentro da função que envia um parâmetro ex: func('array'), o this dentro da função fica como this = array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é gerado pela natureza do método `addEventListener`. Quando ele chama a callback que lhe passas o contexto de execução muda (ie: o this). Tens várias maneiras de resolver isso:

- usando arrow functions
- usando `.call`, `.apply`, `.bind`
- usando classes ES6

Exemplos:

#### Com arrow function:

```
smartPlayer.prototype.initPlayer = function(){

    /* Event button play */
    playMusic.addEventListener("click", () => { // <---- repara aqui!
        if (this.trackCurrentInfo === undefined) {
            this.trackList = getDailyrMusic();
            this.trackCurrentList = 0;
        }

        var track = this.trackList[this.trackCurrentList];
        this._callTrack(track);
    });
}
```

#### Com `.bind`:

```
smartPlayer.prototype.initPlayer = function(){
    var self = this;

    /* Event button play */
    playMusic.addEventListener("click", function(){
        if (this.trackCurrentInfo === undefined) {
            this.trackList = getDailyrMusic();
            this.trackCurrentList = 0;
        }

        var track = this.trackList[this.trackCurrentList];
        this._callTrack(self, track);
    }.bind(this)); // <------ repara aqui!
}
```

#### Usando ES6:

```js
class smartPlayer {
  constructor() {
    /* Event button play */
    playMusic.addEventListener("click", this.playTrack.bind(this));
  }
  playTrack(nr) {
    if (this.trackCurrentInfo === undefined) {
      this.trackList = this.getDailyrMusic();
      this.trackCurrentList = 0;
    }

    var track = this.trackList[this.trackCurrentList];
    this._callTrack(track);
  }

  getDailyrMusic() {
    // algo...
  }
  _callTrack(self, array) {
    /* set current Track infos */
    this.trackCurrentInfo = {
      "trackAlbumId": array.trackId,
      "trackMusic": array.trackName,
      "trackArtist": array.trackArtist,
      "trackAlbum": array.trackAlbum,
      "trackAlbumCover": array.trackCover,
      "trackCurrentTime": 0,
      "trackFullTime": array.trackDuration
    };

    // update elements
    // console.log(this.trackCurrentInfo)
    trackMusic.innerHTML = this.trackCurrentInfo.trackMusic;
    trackArtist.innerHTML = this.trackCurrentInfo.trackArtist;
    trackAlbum.innetHTML = this.trackCurrentInfo.trackAlbum;
  }
}
```